# Civicrm menu lost for admin

Tags: drupal, menu

When I'm logged in as Admin, I can't access anymore to CiviCRM menu from Drupal 7

[image: menu for admin]

I still access through navigation to https://domain.net/civicrm/admin/ but no main menu anymore. Our users that have another profile can see it.

[image]

I've tried with different administration themes but the issue remains the same.

I'm using Drupal extension "Administration menu" but until now it worked fine.

Any idea to help me work again :-( ?

Comment: Found. It came from the overlay module in Drupal :-(

Comment: Great - could you put that as an answer and accept it (green tick)? It's clearer for others that this is solved.

Comment: Thanks Aidan. done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found. It came from the overlay module in Drupal :-(
I needed to deactivate it.