# CiviCRM 5.26.2 admin menu vanished in Drupal 7.72

Tags: drupal, menu, upgrade

I just upgraded to CiviCRM 5.26.2 using Drupal 7.72. Specific CiviCRM administration pages work fine if I type in the proper urls to access it. But the administration menu just doesn't show at all.

I can't tell when exactly the issues started but it certainly was present in the last version of Drupal/CiviCRM already. I hoped an upgrade would help resolving the issue. Unfortunately this isn't the case.

I have searched guides and tried different approaches. But so far I have not been unsuccessful.

As suggested in an other thread here I tried to [deactivate the overlay admin pages](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/33720/civicrm-menu-lost-for-admin) in Drupal and I also tried to [re-create the navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22653365/restoring-navigation-menu-in-civicrm) by emptying the CiviCRM navigation table in the data base and restoring it from what I found in "sites/all/modules/civicrm/sql/civicrm_data.mysql".

I received a list of warnings when I made the CiviCRM update but it was basically just about a soon needed update for MySQL and some changed message templates. (Details further down.)

And the update ended with a blank screen only showing the options to retry or skip. But if I check out the Drupal module list it shows me that CiviCRM is in fact installed in the most recent version.

I have no idea what else to do about it. The most important function I quickly need is sending out a newly created newsletter but unfortunately this is the one direct link (of those I tried) I can't figure out. Maybe this is due to some changes in newer versions of CiviCRM?

**Full detailed feedback:**

> Upgrade CiviCRM to Version 5.26.2 Statusmeldung
>
> The database will be upgraded from 5.8.2 to 5.26.2. Warning:
>
> This system uses MySQL/MariaDB v5.5.62-0+deb8u1. You may proceed with
> the upgrade, and CiviCRM v5.26.2 will continue working normally.
> However, CiviCRM v5.28+ will require MySQL v5.6.5+. We recommend MySQL
> v5.7+ or MariaDB v10.1+.
>
> The default copies of the message templates listed below will be
> updated to handle new features or correct a problem. Your installation
> has customized versions of these message templates, and you will need
> to apply the updates manually after running this upgrade. Click here
> for detailed instructions.
>
> ```
> Contributions - Receipt (on-line) - Show recurring cancel/update URLs in receipt based on payment processor capabilities
> Contributions - Recurring Start and End Notification - Show recurring cancel/update URLs in receipt based on payment processor
> ```
>
> capabilities
> Memberships - Receipt (on-line) - Show recurring cancel/update URLs in receipt based on payment processor capabilities
>
> The default copies of the message templates listed below will be
> updated to handle new features or correct a problem. Your installation
> has customized versions of these message templates, and you will need
> to apply the updates manually after running this upgrade. Click here
> for detailed instructions.
>
> ```
> Additional Payment Receipt or Refund Notification - Update payment notification to remove print text, use email greeting
> ```
>
> The default copies of the message templates listed below will be
> updated to handle new features or correct a problem. Your installation
> has customized versions of these message templates, and you will need
> to apply the updates manually after running this upgrade. Click here
> for detailed instructions.
>
> ```
> Pledges - Acknowledgement - Use email greeting and fix capitalization
> ```
>
> The default copies of the message templates listed below will be
> updated to handle new features or correct a problem. Your installation
> has customized versions of these message templates, and you will need
> to apply the updates manually after running this upgrade. Click here
> for detailed instructions.
>
> ```
> Contributions - Duplicate Organization Alert - Fix missing Email greetings
> Contribution Invoice Receipt - Fix missing Email greetings
> Contributions - Receipt (off-line) - Fix missing Email greetings
> Contributions - Receipt (on-line) - Fix missing Email greetings
> Contributions - Recurring Billing Updates - Fix missing Email greetings
> Contributions - Recurring Cancellation Notification - Fix missing Email greetings
> Contributions - Recurring Updates - Fix missing Email greetings
> Contributions - Recurring Start and End Notification - Fix missing Email greetings
> Events - Registration Confirmation and Receipt (off-line) - Fix missing Email greetings
> Events - Registration Confirmation and Receipt (on-line) - Fix missing Email greetings
> Events - Receipt only - Fix missing Email greetings
> Memberships - Auto-renew Billing Updates - Fix missing Email greetings
> Memberships - Auto-renew Cancellation Notification - Fix missing Email greetings
> Memberships - Signup and Renewal Receipts (off-line) - Fix missing Email greetings
> Memberships - Receipt (on-line) - Fix missing Email greetings
> Events - Registration Cancellation Notice - Fix missing Email greetings
> Events - Registration Confirmation Invite - Fix missing Email greetings
> Events - Pending Registration Expiration Notice - Fix missing Email greetings
> Events - Registration Transferred Notice - Fix missing Email greetings
> Additional Payment Receipt or Refund Notification - Fix missing Email greetings
> Personal Campaign Pages - Admin Notification - Fix missing Email greetings
> Personal Campaign Pages - Owner Notification - Fix missing Email greetings
> Personal Campaign Pages - Supporter Status Change Notification - Fix missing Email greetings
> Personal Campaign Pages - Supporter Welcome - Fix missing Email greetings
> Petition - need verification - Fix missing Email greetings
> Petition - signature added - Fix missing Email greetings
> Pledges - Acknowledgement - Fix missing Email greetings
> Pledges - Payment Reminder - Fix missing Email greetings
> Profiles - Admin Notification - Fix missing Email greetings
> Cases - Send Copy of an Activity - Fix missing Email greetings
> Tell-a-Friend Email - Fix missing Email greetings
> Test-drive - Receipt Header - Fix missing Email greetings
> ```
>
> The default copies of the message templates listed below will be
> updated to handle new features or correct a problem. Your installation
> has customized versions of these message templates, and you will need
> to apply the updates manually after running this upgrade. Click here
> for detailed instructions.
>
> ```
> Memberships - Receipt (on-line) - Fix Membership Receipt
> ```
>
> The default copies of the message templates listed below will be
> updated to handle new features or correct a problem. Your installation
> has customized versions of these message templates, and you will need
> to apply the updates manually after running this upgrade. Click here
> for detailed instructions.
>
> ```
> Contributions - Receipt (off-line) - Add Contributor Name to Offline Contribution receipts; fix bad event self-service URL
> Events - Registration Confirmation Invite - Add Contributor Name to Offline Contribution receipts; fix bad event self-service URL
> ```
>
> The default copies of the message templates listed below will be
> updated to handle new features or correct a problem. Your installation
> has customized versions of these message templates, and you will need
> to apply the updates manually after running this upgrade. Click here
> for detailed instructions.
>
> ```
> Contribution Invoice Receipt - Layout fixes for the Contribution templates
> ```
>
> Back up your database before continuing. This process may change your
> database structure and values. In case of emergency you may need to
> revert to a backup. For more detailed information, refer to the
> Upgrade Documentation.

Update from my web developer network console when accessing my-domain.com//civicrm?reset=1:

```
200 GET my-domain.com   civicrm?reset=1 document    html    8.55 kB 34.72 kB    707 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   jquery.dataTables.min.css   stylesheet  html    384 B   0 B 423 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   font-awesome.min.css    stylesheet  html    385 B   0 B 633 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   jquery-ui.min.css   stylesheet  html    385 B   0 B 679 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   select2.min.css stylesheet  html    385 B   0 B 1393 ms
200 GET my-domain.com   jquery.js?v=1.4.4   script  js  cached  76.76 kB    
200 GET my-domain.com   jquery-extend-3.4.0.js?v=1.4.4  script  js  cached  3.33 kB 
200 GET my-domain.com   jquery-html-prefilter-3.5.0-backport.js?v=1.4.4 script  js  cached  12.33 kB
404 GET my-domain.com   jquery.min.js   script  html    385 B   0 B 636 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   jquery-ui.min.js    script  html    385 B   0 B 636 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   lodash.min.js   script  html    384 B   0 B 1397 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   jquery.mousewheel.min.js    script  html    384 B   0 B 1454 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   select2.min.js  script  html    384 B   0 B 1456 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   jquery.form.min.js  script  html    384 B   0 B 1454 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   jquery.timeentry.min.js script  html    384 B   0 B 1455 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   jquery.blockUI.min.js   script  html    384 B   0 B 1688 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   jquery.dataTables.min.js    script  html    384 B   0 B 1919 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   jquery.validate.min.js  script  html    384 B   0 B 1975 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   additional-methods.min.js   script  html    384 B   0 B 1975 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   jquery.ui.datepicker.validation.min.js  script  html    384 B   0 B 1975 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   jquery.tableHeader.js   script  html    384 B   0 B 1973 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   jquery.notify.min.js    script  html    384 B   0 B 2095 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   jquery.smartmenus.min.js    script  html    384 B   0 B 2312 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   jquery.smartmenus.keyboard.min.js   script  html    384 B   0 B 2482 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   datepicker-de.js    script  html    384 B   0 B 2425 ms
200 GET my-domain.com   dashboard.css?r=eeWQL   stylesheet  css 1.80 kB 4.45 kB 1987 ms
200 GET my-domain.com   system.base.css?qc8ckd  stylesheet  css 2.17 kB 5.30 kB 1987 ms
200 GET my-domain.com   system.menus.css?qc8ckd stylesheet  css 996 B   1.99 kB 1999 ms
200 GET my-domain.com   system.messages.css?qc8ckd  stylesheet  css 717 B   961 B   1999 ms
200 GET my-domain.com   system.theme.css?qc8ckd stylesheet  css 1.52 kB 3.62 kB 2013 ms
200 GET my-domain.com   jquery.ui.core.css?qc8ckd   stylesheet  css 0.98 kB 1.42 kB 2014 ms
200 GET my-domain.com   jquery.ui.theme.css?qc8ckd  stylesheet  css 3.25 kB 18.69 kB    2028 ms
200 GET my-domain.com   overlay-parent.css?qc8ckd   stylesheet  css 848 B   1.10 kB 2028 ms
200 GET my-domain.com   shadowbox.css?qc8ckd    stylesheet  css 1.08 kB 2.16 kB 2041 ms
200 GET my-domain.com   comment.css?qc8ckd  stylesheet  css 476 B   184 B   2039 ms
200 GET my-domain.com   date.css?qc8ckd stylesheet  css 1.50 kB 3.65 kB 2051 ms
200 GET my-domain.com   datepicker.1.7.css?qc8ckd   stylesheet  css 1.21 kB 3.63 kB 2056 ms
200 GET my-domain.com   field.css?qc8ckd    stylesheet  css 570 B   550 B   2063 ms
200 GET my-domain.com   node.css?qc8ckd stylesheet  css 443 B   144 B   2079 ms
200 GET my-domain.com   search.css?qc8ckd   stylesheet  css 567 B   564 B   2078 ms
200 GET my-domain.com   user.css?qc8ckd stylesheet  css 1.01 kB 1.78 kB 2088 ms
200 GET my-domain.com   shortcut.css?qc8ckd stylesheet  css 983 B   2.35 kB 2117 ms
200 GET my-domain.com   views.css?qc8ckd    stylesheet  css 644 B   707 B   2093 ms
200 GET my-domain.com   ckeditor.css?qc8ckd stylesheet  css 521 B   431 B   2107 ms
200 GET my-domain.com   admin_menu.css?qc8ckd   stylesheet  css 1.82 kB 5.17 kB 2112 ms
200 GET my-domain.com   admin_menu.uid1.css?qc8ckd  stylesheet  css 489 B   173 B   2107 ms
200 GET my-domain.com   admin_menu_toolbar.css?qc8ckd   stylesheet  css 1.45 kB 3.24 kB 2117 ms
200 GET my-domain.com   ctools.css?qc8ckd   stylesheet  css 583 B   509 B   2127 ms
200 GET my-domain.com   crm-i.css?qc8ckd    stylesheet  css 875 B   1 kB    2134 ms
200 GET my-domain.com   crm-menubar.f66e6e59265b6ce8981d37ae3fd6eb68.css?qc8ckd stylesheet  css 3.26 kB 12.28 kB    2135 ms
200 GET my-domain.com   civicrm.css?qc8ckd  stylesheet  css 16.30 kB    82.74 kB    2154 ms
200 GET my-domain.com   common.css?qc8ckd   stylesheet  css 2.77 kB 11.71 kB    2149 ms
200 GET my-domain.com   responsive.css?qc8ckd   stylesheet  css 1.24 kB 4.88 kB 2147 ms
200 GET my-domain.com   jquery.once.js?v=1.2    script  js  cached  2.90 kB
200 GET my-domain.com   drupal.js?qc8ckd    script  js  cached  19.75 kB
200 GET my-domain.com   jquery.ui.core.min.js?v=1.8.7   script  js  cached  4.22 kB
200 GET my-domain.com   jquery.ba-bbq.js?v=1.2.1    script  js  cached  4.02 kB 
200 GET my-domain.com   overlay-parent.js?v=1.0 script  js  cached  37.52 kB    
200 GET my-domain.com   shadowbox.js?v=3.0.3    script  js  cached  76.75 kB    
200 GET my-domain.com   shadowbox_auto.js?v=3.0.3   script  js  cached  2.40 kB 
200 GET my-domain.com   Common.js?qc8ckd    script  js  cached  60.63 kB    
200 GET my-domain.com   crm.datepicker.js?qc8ckd    script  js  cached  7 kB    
200 GET my-domain.com   crm.ajax.js?qc8ckd  script  js  cached  22.88 kB    
200 GET my-domain.com   crm.wysiwyg.js?qc8ckd   script  js  cached  2.42 kB 
200 GET my-domain.com   de_DE?cid=2&r=eeWQL script  js  cached  6.06 kB 
200 GET my-domain.com   crm.menubar.js?qc8ckd   script  js  cached  20.29 kB    
200 GET my-domain.com   jquery.dashboard.js?qc8ckd  script  js  cached  20.66 kB    
200 GET my-domain.com   noconflict.js?qc8ckd    script  js  cached  103 B
200 GET my-domain.com   admin_menu.js?qc8ckd    script  js  cached  12 kB   
200 GET my-domain.com   admin_menu_toolbar.js?qc8ckd    script  js  cached  1.54 kB 
200 GET my-domain.com   de_zy608z44xT2fS_YmNk5jj1-EILezSIP2Wkc9qwaUyrM.js?qc8ckd    script  js  cached  3.50 kB 
200 GET my-domain.com   all.js?qc8ckd   script  js  cached  4.68 kB 
200 GET my-domain.com   d3.min.js   script  js  cached  143.31 kB   
200 GET my-domain.com   crossfilter.min.js  script  js  cached  22.28 kB    
200 GET my-domain.com   dc.min.js   script  js  cached  86.71 kB
404 GET my-domain.com   jquery.min.js   script  html    384 B   0 B 406 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   jquery-ui.min.js    script  html    384 B   0 B 381 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   lodash.min.js   script  html    384 B   0 B 378 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   jquery.mousewheel.min.js    script  html    384 B   0 B 361 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   select2.min.js  script  html    384 B   0 B 357 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   jquery.form.min.js  script  html    384 B   0 B 355 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   jquery.timeentry.min.js script  html    384 B   0 B 345 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   jquery.blockUI.min.js   script  html    384 B   0 B 358 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   jquery.dataTables.min.js    script  html    384 B   0 B 367 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   jquery.validate.min.js  script  html    384 B   0 B 456 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   additional-methods.min.js   script  html    384 B   0 B 372 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   jquery.ui.datepicker.validation.min.js  script  html    384 B   0 B 372 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   jquery.tableHeader.js   script  html    384 B   0 B 367 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   jquery.notify.min.js    script  html    384 B   0 B 373 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   jquery.smartmenus.min.js    script  html    384 B   0 B 376 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   jquery.smartmenus.keyboard.min.js   script  html    384 B   0 B 370 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   datepicker-de.js    script  html    384 B   0 B 1027 ms
404 GET my-domain.com   favicon.ico img html    cached  294 B   93 requests
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fantastic, like [Jon G - Megaphone Tech](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/12/jon-g-megaphone-tech) mentioned in the comments: I replaced the formerly working shortlink including my domain name with the internal link using the auto-generated "clients" structure for $civicrm_root (and in the following line with the templates_c link) in my civicrm.settings.php file and now finally the CiviCRM menu appears again.

Answer (score 2):

Some things to try:

- Delete your [templates_c](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/15932/12) folder.
- Press F12 in your browser to open the developer tools.  Go to the **Network** tab, and reload the page.  Check the status for any file that doesn't return with a `200` status.
- Also look for the `l10n.js` file.  Open it in a new tab.  Is there any additional text at the top that shouldn't be there?  If you're not sure, do the same thing on the [demo servers](https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/).

Comment: Thank you very much. I find that loads of jquery files and css files can not be found (after I have deleted my templates_c folder). Do you have an idea how to fix this? Doesn't come CiviCRM with its own versions of that per default?

Comment: I have also deleted my Drupal cache. I can only find a "l10n.js.tpl" file in my Drupal sites folder. (I have used the locate command on the bash for my search.)

Comment: All missing files seem to sit either in /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/ or /sites/all/modules/civicrm/bower_components/.

Comment: Ah - have you installed from git, or from a tarball?

Comment: I just used the official tar: https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-5.26.2-drupal.tar.gz

Comment: Is the resource url setting at /civicrm/admin/setting/url?reset=1 correct? Do you have anything in civicrm.settings.php like $civicrm_root that might be pointing to the wrong spot?

Comment: It looks reasonable to me: $civicrm_root = '/var/www/my-domain.com/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm';

Comment: Hmm a drupal 7 site with a separate "web" folder. Was drupal originally installed with composer?

Comment: With a path like that, I'm guessing there's no symlinks in it - but if you're using symlinks you may run into trouble (I think especially on MacOS?  Don't recall).  Anyway, if any of your paths have symlinks, substitute in the absolute path.  Also - the l10n.js is derived from the `.tpl` file you mention, which generates JS on the fly. What we're looking for here is a Drupal module or theme file that adds text or headers to all rendered `.tpl` files. This obviously results in a JS error, which can cause the menu to not load.

Comment: It is a setup with multible domains on a virtual server. We are using ISPConfig for our administration which creates a folder structure like "/var/www/clients/client10/web11/web/." But for all practical purposes the alternative "/var/www/my-domain.com/web/" can be used instead. Unfortunately I am still not sure where to replace paths. And I am not aware that I ever needed to use the internal paths anywhere else in any web project so far (except when dealing with local backups because rsync would always refer to the most recent version if I didn't use the real path with the "clients" hierarcy).

Comment: The issue is that Civi has a function that matches paths to URLs.  However, there's no OS-agnostic way to get the correct paths when symlinks are involved.  See [core#1497](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1497) and the related discussions linked therein.  These paths can be set from `civicrm.settings.php`, and also in **Administer » System Settings » Directories**.  I would look over both and change any symlinked paths to their real path, clear caches/`templates_c`, and hopefully you should be good to go. UPDATE: Ah, never mind, I see you did it already!

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue. I changed the resource urls from portable to absolute and that fixed the problem.